# Add new Quote button on Unified Interface not working

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I've just moved over to v9 from v8 on a on-premise instance of Dynamics and I'm messing around with the Unified Interface.

I've encountered an issue where the **Add New Quote** button on the quote subgrid in the opportunity form doesn't do anyting when it's pressed.

Can anyone give me some sort of direction on how to fix this issue?

Comment: See if this is helpful - https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/350793/no-add-quote-button-on-quote-subgrid-on-the-opportunity-entity-in-unified-interface/938911

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked through the post and checked everything suggested but it still doesn't work